# Link errors with stringstream

Tags: c++, opencv

I am building an win32 application that is statically linked with OpenCV libraries. Upon the first try, I was instructed by the build log to ignore default libraries, msvcprtd.lib and libcmtd.lib as there were lots lots of link errors such as

```
"LIBCMTD.lib(sprintf.obj) : error LNK2005: _sprintf already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR100D.dll)"
```

The last two sentences in the build log were

```
1>LINK : warning LNK4098: defaultlib 'MSVCRTD' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library
1>LINK : warning LNK4098: defaultlib 'LIBCMTD' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library
```

After I exclude these two libraries, I am not able to use stringstream or cout as I get the following build errors:

```
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > std::cout" (__imp_?cout@std@@3V?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@1@A)
1>run.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: virtual __thiscall std::basic_iostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::~basic_iostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >(void)" (__imp_??1?$basic_iostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@UAE@XZ) referenced in function __unwindfunclet$??0?$basic_stringstream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@QAE@H@Z$0
1>run.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall std::basic_iostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::basic_iostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >(class std::basic_streambuf<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > *)" (__imp_??0?$basic_iostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QAE@PAV?$basic_streambuf@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@1@@Z) referenced in function "public: __thiscall std::basic_stringstream<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >::basic_stringstream<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >(int)" (??0?$basic_stringstream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@QAE@H@Z)
1>run.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) protected: void __thiscall std::basic_streambuf<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::setp(char *,char *,char *)" (__imp_?setp@?$basic_streambuf@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@IAEXPAD00@Z) referenced in function "protected: virtual int __thiscall std::basic_stringbuf<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >::overflow(int)" (?overflow@?$basic_stringbuf@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@MAEHH@Z)
1>run.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) protected: char * __thiscall std::basic_streambuf<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::pbase(void)const " (__imp_?pbase@?$basic_streambuf@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@IBEPADXZ) referenced in function "protected: virtual int __thiscall std::basic_stringbuf<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >::overflow(int)" (?overflow@?$basic_stringbuf@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@MAEHH@Z)
```

Anyone encounter similar errors?

Comment: Sounds like the OpenCV static libs were built to link against a different MSVS runtime. Did you read the release notes?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help for formatting help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever Visual Studio starts to complain about conflicts between `MSVCRTD.lib` and `LIBCMTD.lib` you can be certain that you are linking together projects that are inconsistently linking in the Microsft runtime elements.

You mentioned that the OpenCV you are using is statically linked and I would bet that your project is dynamically linked.  You should setup your solution file so that you are statically linking all projects or dynamically linking all projects.